# Nation-state digital signatures - how is my public key linked to an identity?

Tags: digital-signature, identity

A bitcoiner trying to understand the nation-states.

When I use my eID (I'm swedish and I have 'BankID'), and I sign something with my private key that's in the 'eID-file' that I've got on my laptop, how does anyone know that the public key I generate is linked to me ?

I can sign something right now using my mobile ID, but how does the service I verify my identity for know that my public key is linked to my identity / passport / personal registration number ?